# Check if item from a Pandas column list contains value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Here is the DF,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'List': ['[7%, 9%, 30%]', '[9%, 30%]', '[7%]'], 'Value' :  ['7%', '0%', '7%']})

List            Value
[7%, 9%, 30%]   7%
[9%, 30%]       0%
[7%]            7%
```

How can I create a new column to check if value is in list column
the expected output

```
List            Value  CTRL
[7%, 9%, 30%]   7%     True
[9%, 30%]       0%     False
[7%]            7%     True
```

Things tried without success..

```
df['CTRL'] = np.where([item for item in df['List']] == df['Value'], True, False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop here, a list comprehension should be the most efficient:

```
df['CTRL'] = [v in l.strip('[]').split(',')
              for l,v in zip(df['List'], df['Value'])]
```

Or, you you have lists (not strings as in the question):

```
df['CTRL'] = [v in l for l,v in zip(df['List'], df['Value'])]
```

output:

```
            List Value   CTRL
0  [7%, 9%, 30%]    7%   True
1      [9%, 30%]    0%  False
2           [7%]    7%   True
```

Comment: thanks for your help but in the full df, here is the error 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Then you don't have the same object as in the provided example, just use `[v in l for l,v in zip(df['List'], df['Value'])]`